# Why is pyplot having issues with PyQt4's QThread?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4, qthread

I am designing a gui that creates multiple QThreads to be activated. Each thread creates an excel workbook with Pandas Excelwriter and creates a heatmap using seaborn and saves that heatmap (for later use by the user for whatever) and then places it into the excel workbook.

I believe the error is that pyplot is not made into its own instance for the thread that is created..rather a resource that all threads are pointing to..if I run just one thread, there is no issue...two or more threads..in this example 4, there are internal pyplot errors pointing to dictionary size change occurring.

The issue I'm having is when pyplot is put into play. Do I have to do something specific to pyplot like I had to for getting the right backend for matplotlib? I thought the changes I made for matplotlib is inherent to pyplot?

---main.py---

```
import sys
from MAIN_GUI import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from excel_dummy import *


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,22222,33333],[2,44444,55555],[3,44444,22222],[4,55555,33333]]),columns=['hour','input','out'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,22233,33344],[2,44455,55566],[3,44455,22233],[4,55566,33344]]),columns=['hour','input','out'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,23456,34567],[2,98765,45674],[3,44444,22222],[4,44455,34443]]),columns=['hour','input','out'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,24442,33443],[2,44444,54455],[3,45544,24442],[4,54455,33443]]),columns=['hour','input','out'])

df_list = [df1,df2,df3,df4]

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


class MAIN_GUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MAIN_GUI, self).__init__()
        self.uiM = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.uiM.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.uiM.updateALL_Button,QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.newThread)

    def newThread(self):

        count = 0
        for df in df_list:
            count += 1
            Excelify = excelify(df,count)
            self.connect(Excelify,QtCore.SIGNAL('donethread(QString)'),(self.done))
            Excelify.start()


    def done(self):
        print('done')


main_gui = MAIN_GUI()
main_gui.show()
main_gui.raise_()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---excel_dummy.py---

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread
import time
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn.matrix as sm

class excelify(QThread):
    def __init__(self,df,count):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.df = df
        self.count = count

    def run(self):

        heatit = self.heatmap()

        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('donethread(QString)'),'')

    def heatmap(self):

        dfu = pd.DataFrame(self.df.groupby([self.df.input,self.df.hour]).size())
        dfu.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dfu.rename(columns={'0':'Count'})
        dfu.columns=['input','hour','Count']
        dfu_2 = dfu.copy()

        mask=0
        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        fig.set_canvas(FigureCanvas(fig))
        df_heatmap = dfu_2.pivot('input','hour','Count').fillna(0)

        sm.heatmap(df_heatmap,ax=ax,square=True,annot=False,mask=mask)

        plt.ylabel('ID')
        plt.xlabel('Hour')
        plt.title('heatmap for df' + str(self.count))
        plt.savefig(path + '/' + 'heat' + str(self.count) + '.png')
        plt.close()
```

---MAIN_GUI.py---

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.unicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(320,201)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.updateALL_Button = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.updateALL_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40,110,161,27))
        self.updateALL_Button.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.updateALL_Button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Options_updateALL_Button"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 320, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self,MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.updateALL_Button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "updateALL", None))
```

Comment: *"The issue I'm having is when pyplot is put into play"* is not a sufficient problem description. It tells us when the problem occurs, but not what the problem is.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added more description. I thought that my question explained that I don't exactly know what the issue is...If you can please run the program, you would see the issue occurring. I am using python2.7. I hope you can help.

Comment: You may want to read on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also on creating a [Minimal Working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your Code is neither minimal nor working (there are syntax errors and undefined methods). Put everything in one file and remove the stuff that is not need to reproduce the problem (e.g. ExcelWriter is probably not needed at all).

Comment: I added ExcelWriter because I thought that having it effects the behavior of the script since it's coming from a gui. I have had issues that derived from the different behavior pyqt has with pandas ExcelWriter...either way. I took it out and fixed the syntax errors..as far as I can see. I am copying this code from an embedded system so I'm not perfect...but the gist of the issue is that pyplot doesn't play well with pyqt4 when you run this program multiple times. It's as if the memory resource is overlapping when calling pyplot...(plt.ylabel..etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the code in the question is still not really a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (some undefined variable) it is much clearer, where the problem lies.

First, one problem might be that the `MAIN_GUI` class looses a reference to the thread, such that it will be garbage collected before it can finish. One can prevent this by just putting all threads in a list. [See MAIN_GUI code below]

Second, you cannot use pyplot directly to operate on different figures at once. Or in other words, how should pyplot know in which figure to place the ylabel set by `plt.ylabel('ID')` if there exist several at the same time?
The way to solve this, is to create different figures and only work within those figures using the [object oriented](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pythonic_matplotlib.html) approach. [See excelify code below]

Here is the relevant part of the code, where I also changed the signal to return the plot number for easier debugging.

MAIN_GUI:

```
class MAIN_GUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MAIN_GUI, self).__init__()
        self.uiM = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.uiM.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(self.uiM.updateALL_Button,QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.newThread)
        self.threats=[]

    def newThread(self):
        count = 0
        for df in df_list:
            count += 1
            Excelify = excelify(df,count)
            self.connect(Excelify,QtCore.SIGNAL('donethread(int)'),(self.done))
            # appending all threats to a class attribute, 
            # such that they will persist and not garbage collected
            self.threats.append(Excelify)
            Excelify.start()

    def done(self, val=None):
        print('done with {nr}'.format(nr=val))
```

excelify:

```
class excelify(QThread):
    def __init__(self,df,count):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.df = df
        self.count = count

    def run(self):
        heatit = self.heatmap()
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('donethread(int)'),self.count)

    def heatmap(self):
        print ("{nr} started".format(nr=self.count) )
        dfu = pd.DataFrame(self.df.groupby([self.df.input,self.df.hour]).size())
        dfu.reset_index(inplace=True)
        dfu.rename(columns={'0':'Count'})
        dfu.columns=['input','hour','Count']
        dfu_2 = dfu.copy()
        mask=0

        # create a figure and only work within this figure
        # no plt.something inside the threat
        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        fig.set_canvas(FigureCanvas(fig))
        df_heatmap = dfu_2.pivot('input','hour','Count').fillna(0)

        sm.heatmap(df_heatmap,ax=ax,square=True,annot=False,mask=mask)

        ax.set_ylabel('ID')
        ax.set_xlabel('Hour')
        ax.set_title('heatmap for df' + str(self.count))
        fig.savefig( 'heat' + str(self.count) + '.png')
        fig.clear()
        del fig
```